# When user changes variable during execution, not ALL variables/functions with that variable assigned change to the new value

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

The title may seem intimidating, but I still hope someone can help me with the issue I am having. Okay, so I have created a program where, if someone presses any key in "H", "E", "L", "O", "W", "R", and "D", the corresponding letter will be printed in the turtle graphics window. The user can also change the letters' color using any key from F1-F10, change the thickness of each letter by typing any number from 1-0 on the keyboard (0=10), and the user can even change the "dimensions" (Height & Width) of each letter from what they set in the beginning by typing the "K" key and typing the corresponding values into the dialog box that shows up. And the user changing those values is exactly where i am having issues. But first, let be show you my code for the program:

```
" A simple typing program

Press "H" to draw an H
Press "E" to draw an E
Press "L" to draw a L
Press "O" to draw an O
Press "W" to draw a W
Press "R" to draw a R
Press "D" to draw a D
Press "ENTER" to go to the next line
Press "TAB" to make an indent
Press "BACKSPACE" to go backwards an indent
Press the "Up" or "Down" arrow keys to move the turtle up or down the canvas
Press "SPACE" to clear the canvas of your drawings
Press "ESC" to exit the program
Press any number from 1-0 on the key board (1 = 1, 0 = 10) to set the letter thickness
Press any key from F1-F10 to set a random color of the letter
(F1-F8 = colors, F9 = Custom Color, F10 = Original color)

That is all you need to know! Enjoy! """

from turtle import *
from math import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
import copy

# Function variables

space_width = 30 # Default value: 30
letter_height = 100 # Default value: 100
letter_width = 50 # Default value: 50



change = (input("Would you like to change the size of the letters from the defult value? y/any other input: "))

y = ("yes")
n = ("no")


if change in y:
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("Enter a value from 1-170 to set the height of each letter in pixels: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_height > 170:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_height < 1:
                    letter_height = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_height < 1:
            try:
                letter_height = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_height > 170:
                    letter_height = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while True:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("Enter a value from 1-170 to set the width of each letter in pixels: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_width > 170:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_width < 1:
                    letter_width = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
        while letter_width < 1:
            try:
                letter_width = int(input("That value is too little. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
                while letter_width > 170:
                    letter_width = int(input("That value is too much. Please reenter a value from 1-170: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not an integer! Please enter an integer from 1-170!")
            break
    except:
        input("That is not an answer! Please enter either y or n!: ")

elif change in n:
    space_width = 30 # Default value: 30
    letter_height = 100 # Default value: 100
    letter_width = 50 # Default value: 50

#The 'while' loop below will tell the user to choose a color name, but if the color is invalid, an exception is thrown, and the user must reenter a color name until a valid color name is entered. 

while True:
    try:
        pen_color=input("Enter a color name to set the pen color: ")
        pencolor(pen_color)
        break
    except:
        print("That is either not an available color or not a valid color name. Please reenter the name of another color or a valid one.")

def NewLetterDimensions():
    def NewLetterHeight():
        global letter_height
        letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    def NewLetterWidth():
        global letter_width
        letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    NewLetterHeight()
    NewLetterWidth()
    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
    pendown()
    listen()


angle_height = (sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2))
a = (degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))
b = (90-a)
R_angle = (90+b)

D_angle = (90+(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height))))
Second_D_angle = ((90 - (D_angle-90)) + (90-(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))))
D_space_angle = (degrees(atan(letter_width/(letter_height/2))))
space_angle = (180 - R_angle)


def draw_space():
    # Add a space 30 pixels wide.
    penup()
    forward(space_width)
    pendown()

def move_turtle():
    # Pick up the turtle and move it to its starting location.
    penup()
    goto(-200, 100)
    pendown()

def draw_H():
    # Draw the left leg of H.
    # The turtle starts at the bottom left of the letter, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    # Draw the bar of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the top of the left leg, pointing up.
    forward(-letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    # Draw the right leg of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the right side of the bar, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    # The H is drawn.
    # The turtle is in the top right, pointing right.
    draw_space()


def draw_E():
    # Draw an E.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_L():
    # Draw an L
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_O():
    # Draw an O
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_newline():
    # This funtion will pick up the turtle and move it to a second line below HELLO
    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() -letter_height-5)
    pendown()

def draw_W():
    # This function will draw a W
    left(105)
    forward(letter_height)
    backward(letter_height)
    right(40)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(131)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(141)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(165)
    penup()
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    draw_space()

def draw_second_O():
    # This function will draw the O in "world"
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    penup()
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    draw_space()

def draw_R():
    # This function will draw an R
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(R_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    left(space_angle)
    draw_space()

def draw_D():
    # This function will draw a REAL D
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    right(Second_D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    left(90+D_space_angle)
    penup()
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def skip(x, y):
    penup()
    goto(x, y)
    pendown()

def back():
    penup()
    bk(letter_width + space_width)
    pendown()

def walk():
    penup()
    forward(letter_width + space_width)
    pendown()

def soar():
    penup()
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height + 5)
    right(90)
    pendown()

def fall():
    penup()
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height + 5)
    left(90)
    pendown()

setup(1.0, 1.0)

def RotateRight():
    right(90)

def RotateLeft():
    left(90)

def Up():
    penup()
    goto(xcor(),ycor()+(letter_height+5))
    pendown()

def width1():
    width(1)

def width2():
    width(2)

def width3():
    width(3)

def width4():
    width(4)

def width5():
    width(5)

def width6():
    width(6)

def width7():
    width(7)

def width8():
    width(8)

def width9():
    width(9)

def width10():
    width(10)

def Blue():
    color("blue")

def Red():
    color("red")

def DarkGreen():
    color("dark green")

def Purple():
    color("purple")

def Pink():
    color("pink")

def Brown():
    color("brown")

def Orange():
    color("orange")

def Black():
    color("Black")

def OriginalColor():
    color(pen_color)

def getColor():
    Color = askcolor()
    color_name = Color[1]
    colormode(255)
    color(color_name)

move_turtle()
speed(0)
color(pen_color)
listen()
##onkey(Color, "F10")
onkey(NewLetterDimensions, "k")
onkey(width1, "1")
onkey(width2, "2")
onkey(width3, "3")
onkey(width4, "4")
onkey(width5, "5")
onkey(width6, "6")
onkey(width7, "7")
onkey(width8, "8")
onkey(width9, "9")
onkey(width10, "0")
onkey(Blue, "F1")
onkey(Red, "F2")
onkey(DarkGreen, "F3")
onkey(Purple, "F4")
onkey(Pink, "F5")
onkey(Brown, "F6")
onkey(Orange, "F7")
onkey(Black, "F8")
onkey(getColor, "F9")
onkey(OriginalColor, "F10")
onscreenclick(goto)
onscreenclick(skip)
onkey(clear, "space")
onkey(back, "BackSpace")
onkey(walk, "Tab")
onkey(Up, "Up")
onkey(draw_H, "h")
onkey(bye, "Escape")
onkey(draw_E, "e")
onkey(draw_L, "l")
onkey(draw_O, "o")
onkey(draw_W, "w")
onkey(draw_R, "r")
onkey(draw_D, "d")
onkey(draw_newline, "Return")
```

Here:

```
angle_height = (sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2))
a = (degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))
b = (90-a)
R_angle = (90+b)

D_angle = (90+(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height))))
Second_D_angle = ((90 - (D_angle-90)) + (90-(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))))
D_space_angle = (degrees(atan(letter_width/(letter_height/2))))
space_angle = (180 - R_angle)
```

is where I am having my issue as a result of this:

```
def NewLetterDimensions():
    def NewLetterHeight():
        global letter_height
        letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    def NewLetterWidth():
        global letter_width
        letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    NewLetterHeight()
    NewLetterWidth()
    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
    pendown()
    listen()
```

The above code block is what allows the user to change the color value while execution, and is called by the following function:

```
onkey(NewLetterDimensions, "k")
```

The issue is that, when the value changes for the variables in the `NewLetterDimensions()` function, not ALL places assigned that variable change with that value! In fact, the **only** place it does not change here:

```
angle_height = (sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2))
a = (degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))
b = (90-a)
R_angle = (90+b)

D_angle = (90+(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height))))
Second_D_angle = ((90 - (D_angle-90)) + (90-(degrees(acos(letter_width/angle_height)))))
D_space_angle = (degrees(atan(letter_width/(letter_height/2))))
space_angle = (180 - R_angle)
```

When the value is changed, the "R", for instance, gets drawn like this:

[R with the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/560Gx.png)

Instead of like this, how it is supposed to:

[R without the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wl7M.png)

This even goes on with the "D" also, since, as you can see, the "D" uses angles assigned by variables, too. It seems as if ALL the OTHER values assigned to the functions change instead of the values assigned to the variables. Why is this happening, and how would I remedy this? Any help at all is very much appreciated regarding this issue! :)

Comment: Firstly, you never actually update your various angles. A variable's value is set when it is assigned that value and it must be reassigned in order to change. Secondly, this is one of the many dangers of using global variables so liberally. I think you (and I!) would have a much better idea of what's going on if you had functions return the updated values rather than modifying them globally all over the place.

Comment: @Whonut  And also, I assigned the print function to print what both functions `NewLetterHeight()` and `NewLetterWidth()`, and they both output **none**! If that is the case, then how are the values being changed for the letter functions, but not for the variables? And, also, how else would I allow the user to be able to reassign values when the program is running?

Comment: @Whonut Actually, even when I took the global functions out and printed the values of those functions, they still return none! But without the global function, the code just does not implement what i want it to! How else would I implement this then?

Comment: A small terminology point: you don't assign `print`, it's a statement. The functions return `None` because you don't tell them to return anything else. You're using the functions for what are called their 'side effects' (modifying the variables) and not their return value. I will post an answer to illustrate what I mean as soon as I have some working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `from <module> import *` can cause a lot of problems. For example, both `turtle` and `math` have functions called `degrees` defined in them. I had a bug when writing the code below where Python was trying to use `turtle.degrees` instead of `math.degrees`. It is much better not to use `*` & use the module name when calling a function e.g. `a = math.sin(math.pi/2)`. It helps you (and Python!) to know where every object is from, because `math.degrees(foo)` and `turtle.degrees(foo)` are obviously different. You can also import only the things you know you'll need with for example `from turtle import forward, left, penup`

On to your question. This is one of the dangers of using global variables so liberally. With your current method you *have* to alter `letter_width` and `letter_height` globally but the variables calculated from them are another story. What I would do is have each drawing function take width and height arguments and do the maths in the function scope. Something like

```
def draw_R(width, height):
    # This function will draw an R
    slant_height = math.sqrt(width**2 + (height/2)**2)
    slant_angle = math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/slant_height))

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height/2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.left(90+slant_angle)
    turtle.forward(slant_height)
    turtle.left(slant_angle)
    draw_space()
```

Then the `onkey` bind becomes

```
onkey(lambda: draw_R(letter_width, letter_height), "r")
```

You have to use a lambda because technically callbacks can't take arguments. You can also simplify `NewLetterDimensions` like so:

```
def NewLetterDimensions():
    global letter_height
    letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    global letter_width
    letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))

    penup()
    goto(xcor(), ycor() +letter_height)
    pendown()
    listen()
```

If you reorganise your code like this then you remove a lot of the *"Wait, what value does the variable have now?"* confusion of globals.